# Java Hibernate object loses its value after some time

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Java Hibernate Object that loses its value, and I don't understand why or what's happening there.

This is what the code looks like (Not real code)

```
HibernateObject obj = new HibernateObject();
obj.setStringA("A");
obj.setStringB("B");
obj.setSet(aSet); // A Java set

// Then I do some operations (30sec-1min)
// These operations have nothing to do with the HibernateObject
// Then I see that the set is gone, the set has a size of 0. But the strings are there
```

Is it that after sometime the HibernateObject defaults to some previously stored value? A timeout?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I corrected it, just setting a Java Set object.

Comment: Later in your code, do you ever commit/persist this `HibernateObject` object?

Comment: No, not in this flow.

Comment: Where does the reference aSet come from? Maybe it is cleared in some other place in code?

Comment: @JakubGodoniuk, no that reference doesn't get cleared.

Comment: But the set ends up with a 0 size. So something replaces the set in HibernateObject or, something deletes the set contents. You could put a breakpoint/System.out.println() in HibernateObject to catch when a set is replaced. Also, before obj.setSet(aSet), you can try to make a copy of aSet and insert it into obj.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. It works fine in debug mode.

Comment: So using breakpoint will not help, then I would try System.out.println (or some logging).

Comment: So your threads runs for at least 30 seconds when it loses its value??? that's way too much, what are you doing? try detaching your hibernate object i think hibernate is somehow refreshing it values... execute this code just after setting the `obj.setSet(aSet);` line:  `(your javax.persistence.EntityManager implementation object).detach(obj)`.

Comment: Please let me know if (EntityManager).detach(obj) works @nullpointer

Comment: I'll try that and let you know, I am a Hibernate novice.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot disapear by itself. You probably remove it in another thread or you are using different `HibernateObject` on your second check.

To be honest idk how it would behave if you would eg rollback the transaction.

Comment: The theory that I have is that after some 'time', that's configured somewhere I don't know, it just resets the object to some previous value. Because if the operation time is reduced to like 5 seconds, it works fine then.

Comment: Your theory does not rule out other posibilities that I have mentioned.

Comment: It's true, but I can't find another thread anywhere in the code base accessing this object, and I have logging enabled too, don't see anything there as well.

Comment: I never tester what would happen if transaction would expired or when tx is roled back (normaly I just discard all entities). But sinceyou have nice playground for that, try to rollback transaction and see if it will change state of given object.

Comment: Maybe that object is injected by container ?